# How to monitor and log networking latency between group of docker containers?

Tags: docker, networking, monitoring, prometheus, latency

I have a setup of 10 docker containers from different immages in a swarm on 3 machines. I need to monitor and log network latency / packet delays between each container. Is there a right tool for it?

I can implement something like

```
while true; for host in "${my_hosts[*]}"; do ping -c 1 "$host" > latency.log; done done
```

and launch it on each machine, tailing `latency.log` to monitor like `Prometheus`. But it feels like reinvensing a square wheel.

Answer (score 2):

What I have at the end is a setup that:

1. Shares `hosts` between containers by `volume`,
2. Measures latency feeding `hosts` to `fping`,
3. Writes `fping` output to log file,
4. Serves this log file to `Prometheus` by `mtail`.

I've implemented wrapper around `fping` to let it work with `mtail`:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# It wraps `fping -lDe` to give output for multiple hosts one line at time (for `mtail` parser)
# Default `fping -lDe` behavior produce X lines at time where X = number of hosts to ping
# This waits for hosts file with `# docker` section as described in usage guide

echo "Measuing time delays to docker hosts from '$1'"

# take hostnames after '# docker' comment line
hosts=$(cat $1 | sed -n '/# docker/,$p' | sed 1,1d)

trap "exit" INT # exit loop by SIGINT

# start `fping` and write it's output to stdout line by line
stdbuf -oL fping -lDe $hosts |
  while IFS= read -r line
  do
    echo $line
  done
```

And there is `mtail` parser for the log file:

```
gauge delay by host
gauge loss by host

# [<epoch_time>] <host>    : [2], 84 bytes, <delay> ms (0.06 avg, 0% loss)
/\[(?P<epoch_time>\d+\.\d+)\] (?P<host>[\w\d\.]*) : \[\d+\], \d+ \w+, (?P<delay>\d+\.\d+) ms \(\d+\.\d+ avg, (?P<loss>\d+)% loss\)/ {
  delay[$host]=$delay
  loss[$host]=$loss
}
```

Now you can add `fping` and `mtail` to your images to let it serve delays and losses metrics for `Prometheus`.

References:

1. mtail: https://github.com/google/mtail
2. fping: https://fping.org/

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understand what you need , Im implementing something like this myself . 
I tested netdata with prometheus and graphana and metricbeat\filebeat with elastic and kibana 
we choose to use elastic (ELK stack) because in the same DB you can handle metrics and textual data . 
hope i gave you some directions .